# Pausing JS Typewriter

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm using a script on Codepen that mimics a type effect.  http://codepen.io/hi-im-si/pen/DHoup.

Trying to create a simple start/stop button.  I've added the pause svg button and class, but not quite sure how to get it to pause.

Thanks for any assistance!

Here's the script:

```js
var TxtType = function(el, toRotate, period) {
        this.toRotate = toRotate;
        this.el = el;
        this.loopNum = 0;
        this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
        this.txt = '';
        this.tick();
        this.isDeleting = false;
    };

    TxtType.prototype.tick = function() {
        var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
        var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

        if (this.isDeleting) {
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
        } else {
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
        }

        this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">'+this.txt+'</span>';

        var that = this;
        var delta = 200 - Math.random() * 100;

        if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

        if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
        delta = this.period;
        this.isDeleting = true;
        } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
        this.isDeleting = false;
        this.loopNum++;
        delta = 500;
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
        that.tick();
        }, delta);
    };

    window.onload = function() {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('typewrite');
        for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
            var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-type');
            var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
            if (toRotate) {
              new TxtType(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
            }
        }
        // INJECT CSS
        var css = document.createElement("style");
        css.type = "text/css";
        css.innerHTML = ".typewrite > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #fff}";
        document.body.appendChild(css);
    };
```

```css
body {
  background-color:#ce3635;
  text-align: center;
  color:#fff;
  padding-top:10em;
  font-family:Helvetica;
}

* { color:#fff; text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<div class="type-wrap">
<h2>
  <a href="" class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ "Hi, My name is Justin.", "I am Creative.", "I Love Design.", "I Love to Develop." ]'>
    <span class="wrap"></span></a>
</h2>
  
</div>
  
  <div class="controls">
   <a href="#" class="stop-start-btn"><span class="icon-pause"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="30px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g  transform="translate(0, 0)">
<line data-color="color-2" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="9" y1="16" x2="9" y2="8" stroke-linejoin="miter"/>
<line data-color="color-2" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="15" y1="16" x2="15" y2="8" stroke-linejoin="miter"/>
<circle fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="12" cy="12" r="11" stroke-linejoin="miter"/>
</g></svg></span></a>
  
  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
 var TxtType = function(el, toRotate, period) {
    this.toRotate = toRotate;
    this.el = el;
    this.loopNum = 0;
    this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
    this.txt = '';
    this.tick();
    this.lastDeletingStatus=0;
    this.isDeleting = 0;
};
var timer;
TxtType.prototype.tick = function() {
    var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
    var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

    if (this.isDeleting===1) {
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
    } else {
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
    }

    this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">'+this.txt+'</span>';

    var that = this;
    var delta = 200 - Math.random() * 100;

    if (this.isDeleting===1) { delta /= 2; }

    if (this.isDeleting===0 && this.txt === fullTxt) {
        delta = this.period;
        this.isDeleting = 1;
    } else if (this.isDeleting===1 && this.txt === '') {
        this.isDeleting = 0;
        this.loopNum++;
        delta = 500;
    }

    if(this.isDeleting!==2){
    timer=setTimeout(function() {
     that.tick();
        }, delta);
    }
};

TxtType.prototype.toggleStart=function(){
//start back up 
    if(this.isDeleting===2){
        this.isDeleting=this.lastDeletingStatus;
        this.lastDeletingStatus=2;
 }
//stop
else{
    this.lastDeletingStatus=this.isDeleting;
    this.isDeleting=2;
    clearTimeout(timer);
}
}
    var toggleStart=function(){
       txtType.toggleStart();
        txtType.tick();
    }
 var txtType;

    window.onload = function() {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('typewrite');
        for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
            var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-type');
            var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
            if (toRotate) {
  txtType=new TxtType(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
            }
          
        }
        // INJECT CSS
        var css = document.createElement("style");
        css.type = "text/css";
        css.innerHTML = ".typewrite > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #fff}";
        document.body.appendChild(css);
    };
```

```css
body {
    background-color:#ce3635;
    text-align: center;
     color:#fff;
     padding-top:10em;
     font-family:Helvetica;
 }

* { color:#fff; text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<div class="type-wrap">
<h2>
  <a href="" class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ "Hi, My name is Justin.", "I am Creative.", "I Love Design.", "I Love to Develop." ]'>
    <span class="wrap"></span></a>
</h2>
  
</div>
  
  <div class="controls">
     <a href="#" class="stop-start-btn"><span class="icon-pause" ><svg onclick="toggleStart()" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="30px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g  transform="translate(0, 0)">
<line data-color="color-2" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="9" y1="16" x2="9" y2="8" stroke-linejoin="miter"/>
<line data-color="color-2" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="15" y1="16" x2="15" y2="8" stroke-linejoin="miter"/>
<circle fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="12" cy="12" r="11" stroke-linejoin="miter"/>
</g></svg></span></a>
  
  
  </div>
```

isDeleting shouldn't be a boolean. It should be able to hold three values. isDeleting=0, isDeleting=1, isDeleting=2 (which is the stopped state).

Then create a function TxtType.prototype.toggleStart that sets this.isDeleting to 2 if it isn't 2, and sets it to the previous value of this.isDeleting if it is two.

To implement this, do the following:

1) Create a global variable, called txtType. In window.onload, set it equal to new TxtType(...). This way, you can access the object from other functions. It would look something like this:

```
var txtType;

window.onload = function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('typewrite');
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-type');
        var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
        if (toRotate) {
    txtType=new TxtType(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
        }
     }
  ...
};
```

2)Create a global timer variable that you set equal to the timeout call in tick(). That way, you can clear the timer from other functions. That would look something like this:

```
var timer;
TxtType.prototype.tick = function() {
    ......
timer=setTimeout(function() {
        that.tick();
        }, delta);
}
```

3)Wherever isDeleting=false, set isDeleting=0. Whenever isDeleting=true, set isDeleting=1. Put an if statement around setTimeout() so that it only runs if isDeleting!==2 (ie. it is not in the stopped state. If it's in the stopped state we do not want this timer to run).

4)Create a function on the prototype of TxtType called toggleStart as follows:

```
TxtType.prototype.toggleStart=function(){
//start back up 
    if(this.isDeleting===2){
        this.isDeleting=this.lastDeletingStatus;
        this.lastDeletingStatus=2;
 }
//stop
else{
    this.lastDeletingStatus=this.isDeleting;
    this.isDeleting=2;
    clearTimeout(timer);
}
}
```

(Initialize this.lastDeletingStatus to 0 in the constructor of TxtType)

5)Create a global function called toggleStart that you can call from html as follows:

```
  var toggleStart=function(){
       txtType.toggleStart();
        txtType.tick();
    }
```

6)Last step, add onclick="toggleStart()" from the pause svg in your html like this:

```
<svg onclick="toggleStart()" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="30px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
```

Tada!!!!

Comment: Appreciate your answer.  Trying to figure out how to implement it :)

Comment: @siiimple , edited to include implementation in case you are still working on it

Comment: Thanks for your help!  And sorry for the delay.  I've been away :)  Would it be possible to add it into a code snippet?  Thought I had it, but still not working for me.  If not, no worries!  Thanks again.

Comment: There you go :) Any questions?